# Java getClass().getName() it returns the class not the name

Tags: java

The output was Card Card.  It was suppose to be unknown Jane. How do i fix this?  I tried to fix it with Card.getClass().getName() but that gives me another error non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
public class Card

{
    private String name;

    public Card()
    {
        name = "unknown";
    }

    public Card(String name1)
    {
        name = name1 ;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName();
    }
}

public class CardTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Card card ;

        card = new Card() ;
        System.out.println(card) ;
        System.out.println("unknown WAS EXPECTED") ;

        card = new Card("Jane") ;
        System.out.println(card) ;
        System.out.println("Jane WAS EXPECTED") ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getClass()` returns the [Class object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) representing the "Card" class; therefore the code does *not* refer to `Card#getName` method, but rather to [`Class#getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) which dutifully returns "Card".

Simply remove `getClass()`:

```
public String toString()
{
    return getName();
}
```

The previous error (wrt "static") was using `Card.getName()` - don't prefix a *type* to invoke an *instance* method.

Answer (score 9):

Your `toString()` method prints the name of the class of the object:

```
return getClass().getName();
```

The object is an instance of `Card`, so its class is `Card.class`, whose name is `Card`. You want to print the value of the name field. So you simply need

```
return name;
```